# Lightweight Migration

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data

I've been following Marcus Zarra's guide in terms of setting up my document based application.  So far it's been going well however I'm attempting to implement Core Data Lightweight Migration and I've seem to hit a snag.  The only difference between the old version and the new version of the model is a NSString attribute for one of the entities.

In NSDocument I've add the following code:

```
    - (BOOL)configurePersistentStoreCoordinatorForURL:(NSURL *)url ofType:(NSString *)fileType modelConfiguration:(NSString *)configuration storeOptions:(NSDictionary *)storeOptions error:(NSError **)error
    {
        NSMutableDictionary *newStoreOptions;
        if (storeOptions == nil) {
            newStoreOptions = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        }
        else {
            newStoreOptions = [storeOptions mutableCopy];
        }
        [newStoreOptions setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption];
        [newStoreOptions setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption];

        BOOL result = [super configurePersistentStoreCoordinatorForURL:url ofType:fileType modelConfiguration:configuration storeOptions:newStoreOptions error:error];
        NSLog(@"base url:%@ model:%@", [url baseURL], [self managedObjectModel]);
        return result;
  }
```

Just to see what's going on I outputted the error variable returned from the

```
[super configurePersistentStoreCoordinatorForURL:url ofType:fileType modelConfiguration:configuration storeOptions:newStoreOptions error:error];
```

And this is what I got back from Xcode:

```
  NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=512 \"The file couldn\U2019t be saved.\" UserInfo=0x104521930 {NSUnderlyingException=Error validating url for store}";
reason = "Can't add destination store";
```

I've seen a couple of posts on SO citing that some users have had this issue when they're attempting to read/write at the same time, but I don't believe I fall into that category.

Also I don't know if this makes a difference but I setup my application to have two contexts.  One is the root context that writes to the persistentStore and the second is the child context which is where all the action from the UI takes places.  The root context is set as the parent context of the child.

Thanks!

**Update**
Stupid me...I think I have a partial solution, but not sure how this will work on users computers.  So if I uncheck 'Enable App Sandboxing' in the Summary tab everything seems to work.  While this works for me, I will have to turn this on when I submit it to the Mac App Store and not sure how this will affect users.

Comment: What URL are you saving to? On iOS you can't save to the main bundle. Not sure how that works on OS X, but you may want to take a look at that.

Comment: Thanks Scott.  The application is re-opening an old file that was saved with a previous model version.  In the launch process this method is being executed.  So I'm not saving to the bundle (at least...I don't think I am).

Answer (score 0):

Review the doc for `configurePersistentStoreCoordinatorForURL:ofType:modelConfiguration:storeOptions:error`, in particular the `NSError **` parameter. You should pass the address of an `NSError *`, that is `&error` in your case (assuming you've defined `NSError *error` somewhere in elided code). But the value of `&error` is undefined on success. Use something like

```
if (!result) {
    NSLog(@"%@", error.localizedFailureReason);
    // fix it
}
```